# How would I write a regular express to parse a string with optional component, a random structure, symbols and a lot of noise

Tags: regex

I need to parse a string that is comprised of codes and symbols that are designed to represent the performance of a horse in a horse race.   I have provided some samples below.  The string is comprised of three components: Prefix, Score and Suffix.  The score and suffix are always present, however, the prefix is not depending on the particular circumstances and race conditions. The prefix and suffix are comprised of codes and symbols that represent things like racing surface, race conditions, equipment used, etc. There is a legend explaining all the codes. There are also some random characters mixed in that should not be extracted.

My objective is to extract the three components as well as the individual codes that may be present in the prefix and suffix.

```
1. 20- v[ 20Sr25A A UUU GGG 
2. =19- V20Sr28 JJJ
3. 21+ VAWGP30 
4. 16+ Yw16MT25 
5. = 18 Vtf 75GP22 AAA
```

Here are explanations of the five examples above:

```
1. has no prefix, the score is a 20-, the suffix is v [ 20Sr25, nothing else is extracted
2. the prefix is = (turf race), the score 19- and the suffix is V20Sr28, not else is extracted
3. no prefix, score is 21+, suffix is VAWGP30 
4. no prefix, score 16+, suffix is Yw16MT25
5. prefix is =, score is 18, suffix is Vtf 75GP22
```

Here are some general rules for the components:

**Prefix** - Generally simply a collection of symbols. Most symbols are one charter but some are two:(examples separated by commas) =,.,F,..,:,G,^

**Score** - the score is highly structured and comprised of the following characters [0-9,+-"]

**Suffix** - the suffix also has some structure.  Its generally comprised of two parts, some optional symbols that are followed by the far right section. The far right section follows one of two pattern: vvLLdd where vv equals value of race, LL is the location and dd is the day. Alternatively, TTLLdd where TT is type of race, LL is location and dd is day.

My questions are:

```
1. How would a capture the three components, given the optional nature of the prefix?- 3 Capture Groups
2. Do I need to include every possible symbol from the legend in the brackets [ ]
3. How would I turn a suffix like Vtf 75GP22 into six pieces of info: V, t, f, 75,GP, 22
```

Any suggests, guidance or code sample appreciated. - Thanks.

Comment: Does each result line begin at the start of a line?

Comment: What language or regex flavor? Does each line start with a digit followed by a period?

Comment: No, actually there can be two or three results on one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this pattern:

```
(?i)(?<prefix>\S*?)\h*(?<score>\d+[+-]?)\s*(?<suffix>.*?(?:[A-Z]{2}|\d{2})[A-Z]{2}\d{2})
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/zF6lC9/1)

pattern details:

```
(?i)                # make the pattern case-insensitive
(?<prefix>\S*?)     # use a lazy * quantifier to allow an empty prefix
\h*                 # zero or more horizontal spaces
(?<score>\d+[+-]?)  #
\s*                 # optional spaces (can be replaced with \h too)
(?<suffix>          # suffix
    .*?             # all until two letters or two digits
    (?:             # two letters or two digits
        [A-Z]{2}
      |
        \d{2}
    )
    [A-Z]{2}\d{2}   # two letters and two digits
)
```

As you can see, the approach is relatively general without using an comprehensive list of predefined symbols. However, If you know the exact list of possible prefixes, you can write the prefix group like that: `(?<prefix>sub1|sub2|sub3...)??`

To extract the content of the suffix part, you only need to extract the 6 last characters (then you split them 2 by 2), and you split the begining with `\s*`. It's possible to do it in one regex but it isn't very handy nor efficient. ([example](http://regex101.com/r/kK7sV3/1))

Comment: What a grizzly regex. Love it.

Comment: I couldn't agree with Qix more. Very impressive. Thanks.  I appreciate the explanation too.  Many thanks.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor: Thanks, and about the question I asked?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Question on your solution.  Why are two questions marks required if I choose to use the exact list of prefixes: (?<prefix>sub1|sub2|sub3...)??

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor: If I remember well, it was to stay the most general (as possible), assuming that if the prefix can be a number, the way without prefix is tested first (but note that in this case the line is very ambigous, however it can be a way to give a default behavior). If the prefix can't be a number (as described more or less in the requirements) it's not needed to make the quantifier lazy.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to accomplish all you want with just one single regex and nothing else.

Basically, you need to write a rather short script in a language of your choice (scripting languages like Perl, Ruby, Python are likely the fastest option) which uses regex match tests, regex match value extraction, conditional structures and data structures.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use something like ruby to parse the string into it three components and then have a regex for each of the components.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor: Not only that, but also to first determine which components are actually present (question 1) and for example to more thoroughly parse the separate fields (question 3).